# Turbo C++ charecter array to int array

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

im storing a value, say 6 under a character array.
i want to pass the same value 6 to an integet array but simply this code dosent work :

```
char a[3];
gets(a);              (for ex: value of a i.e a[0] is 6)
int b[3];
for(int i=0;i<strlen(a);i++)
b[i]=a[i];
cout<<b;               (it returns 54 nd not 6)
```

the above code stores the INTEGER VALUE of 6 in it. it does not store 6 directly.
i want to store the same no 6 and not the integer value (i.e 54).
any ideas?

thanks in advance

Comment: Visual Studio Express is a free download for goodness's sakes. Who would still be using Turbo C++? It's apparently forcing you to write C code instead of C++ code. Does it not support `fgets`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing character codes, and not integers. If you type `1` on the standard input and store that in a `char`, what will get stored is the ASCII code for `1`, and not the integer value `1`.

Thus, when you assign that to `b[i]`, you should do:

```
b[i] = a[i] - '0'; // Of course, this will make sense only as long
                   // as you provide digits in input.
```

Moreover, doing:

```
cout << b;
```

Will print the address of the `b` array, and not its content. Also, using `strlen()` here is not a great idea, because your array `a` is not null-terminated.

Letting aside the considerations on how type-unsafe this is, here is what you possibly meant to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using std::cout;

int main()
{
    char a[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };
    gets(a);

    int b[3];
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < std::min(strlen(a), 3u); i++)
    {
        b[i] = a[i] - '0';
    //              ^^^^^
        cout << b[i];
    }
}
```

Here is how you would do the above in C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string a;
    getline(std::cin, a);

    std::vector<int> b;
    for (char c : a) { if (std::isdigit(c)) b.push_back(c - '0'); }

    for (int x : b) { std::cout << x << " "; }
}
```

Here is a modification of the above function that should work for C++03 as well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string a;
    getline(std::cin, a);

    std::vector<int> b;
    for (std::string::iterator i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); i++)
    {
        if (std::isdigit(*i)) b.push_back(*i - '0');
    }

    for (std::vector<int>::iterator i = b.begin(); i != b.end(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << *i << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually i tried out the following code using a single charecter '6'. the value returned from the integer array was 6-48-65. could you please explain how? i just wanted the value 6 under b[0] and not its ascii value.True when i access b[0], it displays 6 but why has it stored -48 and -65? can you pls explain?

Comment: @user2229186: Which solution have you used? The first one or the second one?

Comment: pls explain this code using borland turbo c++ 3.0 . my saaignments are to be done wit dat only.

Comment: @user2229186: The first version always reads in 3 values. I've modified it so that it reads *at most* 3 values.

Comment: can you pls pls explain it nd give a generalized coding for any no of values nd display the same exact value and no other garbage values. like if i enter 12 in the char array. i shud see b[0]=1,b[1]=2;

Comment: @user2229186: I cannot do your whole homework. I posted an additional version of the code that should work with C++03 as well. I don't know what turbo c++ 3.0 supports.

Comment: Thank you anyway Andy Prowl for spending your time and effort. help appreciated.

Comment: @user2229186: You're welcome, good luck with your assignment :)